# How to fill before and after NANs by 0 for just one NAN in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 2, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
        [2, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2],
        [2, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 2, 2, 2, np.nan],
        [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2]
    ],
    index=list('abcdefgh'), columns=list('ABCDE')
)

df


      A   B   C   D   E
a   2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
b   NaN 2.0 NaN NaN NaN
c   NaN NaN 2.0 NaN NaN
d   NaN 2.0 2.0 NaN NaN
e   2.0 NaN 2.0 NaN 2.0
f   2.0 NaN NaN 2.0 NaN
g   NaN 2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN
h   2.0 NaN NaN NaN 2.0
```

I would like to fill NaNs by 0 for each row, before and after there is a non-NaN value, only for one NaN for each side of the non-NaN value with pandas.

so my desired output would be the following:

```
     A    B    C    D    E
a  2.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  0.0  2.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  0.0  2.0  0.0  NaN
d  0.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  NaN
e  2.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  2.0
f  2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
g  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  0.0
h  2.0  0.0  NaN  0.0  2.0
```

I know how to do it with for loops, but I was wondering if it is possible do it only with pandas.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No! I want to keep them as NaN value! :)

Comment: so you mean it is just horizontal?

Comment: Yes it is just horizontal, maybe I was not specific enough but this what I tried to mean with "for each row" !

Comment: I guess I was too enthusiastic ;) Check my fixed answer, and have a look at the scipy solution if you tend to do this kind of transformation a lot, it is quite powerful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `shift` backward and forward on both axes and `mask`:

```
cond = (df.notna().shift(axis=1, fill_value=False)     # check left
       |df.notna().shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value=False) # check right
       )&df.isna()                                     # cell is NA

df.mask(cond, 0)
```

output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E
a  2.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  0.0  2.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  0.0  2.0  0.0  NaN
d  0.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  NaN
e  2.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  2.0
f  2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
g  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  0.0
h  2.0  0.0  NaN  0.0  2.0
```

NB. This transformation is called a binary dilation, you can also use [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) for that. The advantage with this method is that you can use various structurating elements (not only Left/Right/Top/Bottom)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

struct = np.array([[True, False, True]])
df.mask(binary_dilation(df.notna(), structure=struct), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But there are many errors, for example (h, C) and (d,E) should be NaN. :)

Comment: sorry, I misread, then just remove the first two conditions (above/below)

Comment: (b, A) & (d, A) ;& (g, A) should be 0 too :(

Comment: here it is, I had forgotten to fill with False (else NaN take over), but as I said, the scipy solution is really the best